# Selenium internals

Tags: .net, selenium, testing, automated-tests

How does selenium work? Can you explain the internal working of it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What exactly are you looking for? How is it put together architecturally? How does it manage to execute generic tasks on any web page?

Comment: as Alex said please clarify what exactly you want to know. Architecture, how it talks to browser, or how it preform any operation on any web element etc...

Answer (score 5):

First there's a layer of javascript code that is used to automate the browser and simulate events, run and verify tests. Next, you run a proxy server - which you point your browser to - that injects this javascript code. Then, you can talk to this proxy server through another port using a set of commands which causes the proxy server to inject javascript code to be run on(or remote controlling) the running browser. Using this framework you can write automated test scripts in a style very much like writing macros for the browser.

Comment: I think it might be different if you're using Selenium 2.  http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#the-selenium-server-when-to-use-it

Comment: RC is now obsoleted, because of all this injection of javascript application/browser used to behave differently and that why selenium 2.0 or webdriver came.

Answer (score 3):

[How Selenium Works](http://selenium.openqa.org/about/how.html)

Even has some pretty images. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it works on following principal . It first Searches for element which you specify in your **Locator** by searching it in HTML document shown in driver launched browser . After finding element it gets location of Object.After getting that location  ROBOT Class methods like MOUSECLICK MOUSE Move etc to perform actions on these locations.I hope this works  :-)

Answer (score 0):

**I) If it is selenium RC then the process will be,**

---

1. Your script reaches the selenium server(which you started in
   specific port)
2. In server script will be converted to "Java
   Script"(Which will be understandable by all the browser)
3. Then
   it reaches the browser and do the further actions based on the
   script(type, click etc).. If element not found then it will through
   exception. :)

**II) If it is selenium webdriver then the process will be,**

---

1. Instead of the above process, Script will be directly interact to
   the specified browser(Using browser API) -> Then do the further
   actions.